# Curl file upload stream

Tags: curl

I am doing the following in the MS-DOS Windows.

In "inspect->Copy as cURL (cmd)" Chrome to monitor the file upload returns me:

```
curl "http://up11.usersfiles.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_id=303797686054&js_on=1&utype=anon&upload_type=file" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: http://usersfiles.com/" -H "Origin: http://usersfiles.com" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM" --data-binary "------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""upload_type"""^

"file"^
"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""sess_id"""^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""srv_tmp_url"""^

"http://up11.usersfiles.com/tmp"^
"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file_0""; filename=""prueba.mp4"""^
"Content-Type: video/mp4"^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""undefined_descr"""^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""link_rcpt"""^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""link_pass"""^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""to_folder"""^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file_1""; filename="""""^
"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""submit_btn"""^

" Start Upload "^
"------WebKitFormBoundaryKWLS1B0x6JrGdgBM--"^
"" --compressed
```

This does not work in Windows in MS-DOS, how can I make it work for me? I'm not sure how to use --data-binary. Could you help me?

Comment: If the first command works, then the server accepts multipart. You can't just up and decide what content-type you as a client want to send. The server needs to support handling that type.

Comment: If your question is that you just want to set the type of one part, in the multipart request, you can do `-F "file1_1=@thefile;type=application/octet-stream"`

Comment: There I modified my question because I could not explain myself well.